# How to concatenate lists together based on index

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a piece of code below where it iterates through each field of title, first name and surname and places them into lists:

```
public List<string> GetPassengerNames()
{
    List<string> titleList = new List<string>();
    List<string> forenameList = new List<string>();
    List<string> surnameList = new List<string>();
    List<string> fullNameList = new List<string>();

    var passengerTitles =  _driver.FindElements(PassengerDetailsElements.TitleField);
    var passengerForenames =_driver.FindElements(PassengerDetailsElements.ForenameField);
    var passengerSurnames = _driver.FindElements(PassengerDetailsElements.SurnameField);

    foreach (var passengerTitle in passengerTitles)
    {
        SelectElement passengerTitleSelected = new SelectElement(passengerTitle);
        string passengerTitleText = passengerTitleSelected.SelectedOption.Text;
        titleList.Add(passengerTitleText);

    }

    foreach (var passengerForename in passengerForenames)
    {
        forenameList.Add(passengerForename.GetAttribute("value"));
    }

    foreach (var passengerSurname in passengerSurnames)
    {
        surnameList.Add(passengerSurname.GetAttribute("value"));
    }
}
```

This returns the following for two passengers:

```
titleList Count=2
[0] "Mr"
[1] "Miss"

forenameList Count=1
[0] "Test"
[1] "Tester"

surnameList Count=1
[0] "Testette"
[1] "Testing"
```

Now I want to include one more method above and what I want to do is concatenate the title, forenames and surnames together based on index. I tired the below but it has failed and wanted help on implementing this:

```
foreach (var passengerFullName in passengerTitles.Concat(passengerForenames).Concat(passengerSurnames))
{
    fullNameList.Add(passengerFullName.Text);
}

return fullNameList;
```

So the output I require is:

```
fullNameList Count = 2
[0] "Mr Test Testette"
[1] "Miss Tester Testing"
```

Comment: Why not just use string tokenization instead of multiple Lists ?

List<string> containing
[0] "Mr~Test~Testette"
[1] "Miss~Tester~Testing"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Enumerable.Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) could help you to achieve that:

```
List<string> title = new List<string> { "Mr", "Miss" };
List<string> surname = new List<string> { "Test", "Tester" };
List<string> lastname = new List<string> { "Testette", "Testing" };

List<string> combined = title.Zip(
                    surname.Zip(lastname,  (first, second) => first + " " + second), 
                    (first, second) => first + " " + second).ToList();
```

The method

> Applies a specified function to the corresponding elements of two sequences, producing a sequence of the results.

So in your case you would melt first the names together and then combine the resulting collection with the elements from the `title` List using `" "` space as the separator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mong Zhu, i am assuming this will work no matter how many passengers are in the list?

Comment: So lets say I have 4 passenger titles, 4 first names and 4 surnames, would the code you provided work or will it require additonal first and second?

Comment: @BruceyBandit it will work also with more than 2 elements. if the amound of elements is not equal in 2 collections, it will take only the shortest one, because it has matching elements in the longer collection. So it will cut the tail away that is too long

Comment: While this is cool and very useful, you will get unpredictable results if there's ever a case where the size of the three lists don't match up exactly. You really would be better off building the list as you go while you scrape the site one customer at a time. That way you ensure that there are no discrepancies.